# Fcm - There was an error loading storage bucket

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have made an app and integrated firebase into it. But, when I want to send a notification from Firebase - Engage - Messaging to my app it goes very late, and sometimes it doesn't go. I also see an error like this: There was an error loading the storage bucket

What is the reason? Any helps?

Is it from server or from my code?

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:overlay_support/overlay_support.dart';
import 'package:push_notification/notification_badge.dart';
import 'package:push_notification/push_notification_model.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OverlaySupport(
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: const HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  //init some values
  late final FirebaseMessaging _messaging;
  late int _totalNotificationCounter;

//model
  PushNotificationModel? _notificationInfo;

//register notification
  void registerNotification() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    //instance for firebase messaging
    _messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

    //three type of state in notification
    //not determined(null), granted(true) and decline (false)

    NotificationSettings settings = await _messaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );

    if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
      print("User granted the permission");

      //main message

      FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
        PushNotificationModel notification = PushNotificationModel(
          title: message.notification!.title,
          body: message.notification!.body,
          dataTitle: message.data["title"],
          dataBody: message.data["body"],
        );

        setState(() {
          _totalNotificationCounter++;
          _notificationInfo = notification;
        });

        if (notification != null) {
          showSimpleNotification(
            Text(_notificationInfo!.title!),
            leading:
                NotificationBadge(totalNotificaion: _totalNotificationCounter),
            subtitle: Text(_notificationInfo!.body!),
            background: Colors.cyan[700],
            duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
          );
        }
      });
    } else {
      print("permission declined by user");
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    registerNotification();
    _totalNotificationCounter = 0;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Push Notification"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text(
              "Bildirim",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 20,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 12),

            // showing notification badge which
            //will count the total notification
            //that we receive
            NotificationBadge(totalNotificaion: _totalNotificationCounter),
            const SizedBox(height: 32),

            // if notificationInfo is not null
            _notificationInfo != null
                ? Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "Başlık : ${_notificationInfo!.dataTitle ?? _notificationInfo!.title}",
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 16,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 12),
                      Text(
                        "İçerik : ${_notificationInfo!.dataBody ?? _notificationInfo!.body}",
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 16,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                : Container(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I had the same issue. I don't even use firebase storage.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error in Firebase Cloud Messaging. but when I initialized everything in RealTime Database and Storage from firebase, I chose the database location when I was initializing the real-time database (US central). this worked for me, hope it will work for you also.

Answer (score 0):

try using fcm token

final fcmToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();

add this token in your firebase

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).